# I want to reduce the code in Android

Tags: java, android

This code works well in the main activity. I have used this code number of times in different buttons.
How can i make a class using this code so as to remove repeated code.
I have  "if( ba1x[i]==x3&&ba1y[j]==y3) to  if( ba10x[i]==x3&&ba10y[j]==y3)" for ten buttons.

```
  if(pevent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    x3=(int)pevent.getRawX();
                    y3=(int)pevent.getRawY()-130;
                //  b4.setText("ss"+x3+y3);
                        for(int i=0;i<67;i++){
                            for(int j=0;j<67;j++){

                             if( ba1x[i]==x3&&ba1y[j]==y3)
                             {
                                 for(int a=0;a<=3;a++){
                                     if(xp1==0&&f1[a]==null){
                                         f1[a]=(Integer) ib1.getTag();
                                         xp1=1;
                                         if(xd1==0&&yd1==0){

                                             xd1=(int) ib1.getX();
                                             yd1=(int) ib1.getY();
                                             b.touch_start(xd1,yd1);
                                             b.invalidate();
                                             }
                                                if(xd2==0&&yd2==0){

                                                     xd2=(int) ib2.getX();
                                                     yd2=(int)ib2.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd3==0&&yd3==0){

                                                     xd3=(int)ib3.getX();
                                                     yd3=(int)ib3.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd4==0&&yd4==0){

                                                     xd4=(int)ib4.getX();
                                                     yd4=(int)ib4.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd5==0&&yd5==0){

                                                     xd5=(int)ib5.getX();
                                                     yd5=(int)ib5.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd6==0&&yd6==0){

                                                     xd6=(int)ib6.getX();
                                                     yd6=(int)ib6.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd7==0&&yd7==0){

                                                     xd7=(int)ib7.getX();
                                                     yd7=(int)ib7.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd8==0&&yd8==0){

                                                     xd8=(int)ib8.getX();
                                                     yd8=(int)ib8.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd9==0&&yd9==0){

                                                     xd9=(int)ib9.getX();
                                                     yd9=(int)ib9.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd10==0&&yd10==0){

                                                     xd10=(int)ib10.getX();
                                                     yd10=(int)ib10.getY();
                                                     }
                                                else{

                                                     xd1=(int)ib1.getX();
                                                     yd1=(int)ib1.getY();
                                                     b.touch_move(xd1, yd1);
                                                     b.invalidate();
                                                     rl.addView(b);

                                                }


                                     }


                                 }  
                             }  

                             if( ba2x[i]==x3&&ba2y[j]==y3)
                             {
                                 for(int a=0;a<=3;a++){
                                     if(xp2==0&&f1[a]==null){
                                         f1[a]=(Integer) ib2.getTag();
                                         xp2=1;
                                         if(xd1==0&&yd1==0){

                                             xd1=(int) ib1.getX();
                                             yd1=(int) ib1.getY();

                                             }
                                                if(xd2==0&&yd2==0){

                                                     xd2=(int) ib2.getX();
                                                     yd2=(int)ib2.getY();
                                                     b.touch_start(xd2,yd2);
                                                     b.invalidate();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd3==0&&yd3==0){

                                                     xd3=(int)ib3.getX();
                                                     yd3=(int)ib3.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd4==0&&yd4==0){

                                                     xd4=(int)ib4.getX();
                                                     yd4=(int)ib4.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd5==0&&yd5==0){

                                                     xd5=(int)ib5.getX();
                                                     yd5=(int)ib5.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd6==0&&yd6==0){

                                                     xd6=(int)ib6.getX();
                                                     yd6=(int)ib6.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd7==0&&yd7==0){

                                                     xd7=(int)ib7.getX();
                                                     yd7=(int)ib7.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd8==0&&yd8==0){

                                                     xd8=(int)ib8.getX();
                                                     yd8=(int)ib8.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd9==0&&yd9==0){

                                                     xd9=(int)ib9.getX();
                                                     yd9=(int)ib9.getY();
                                                     }
                                                if(xd10==0&&yd10==0){

                                                     xd10=(int)ib10.getX();
                                                     yd10=(int)ib10.getY();
                                                     }
                                                else{

                                                     xd2=(int)ib2.getX();
                                                     yd2=(int)ib2.getY();
                                                     b.touch_move(xd2, yd2);
                                                     b.invalidate();
                                                     rl.addView(b);
                                                }

                                     }


                                 }            


                             }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all the buttons currently in the same class?  Because if so, you can just make a method that does the work, and call it for each button, passing as method arguments any variables that change from button to button.  If not, you can still make a method, but you'll just have to make it public and place it in a class that all the others have access to.

And user1071777's comment about using arrays (e.g. `int[] xd = int[10]`) instead of many discrete variables is spot-on as well.  Then you can run a for loop (`for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )`) where you test whether `xd[i] == yd[i]`.